# Facebook Canvas URL redirection to 404 Page of Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I had created a `facebook` canvas app and till now using canvas page `url` as

https://apps.facebook.com/272901126185053/

But now while opening that URL its redirecting to 404 page of Facebook. Means that canvas app not exist. But which was working perfect fine earlier

I try to research on `facebook` Developers page but unable to get much help from it.

Comment: It’s a recent bug that affected lots of developers and their apps – they are working on it, so the best thing to do is just relax and wait a few hours. See also my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231103/fb-deactivated-all-my-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Canvas URL` can't be : `https://apps.facebook.com/272901126185053/`

It should the URL to the app where it is hosted. The link you mentioned is the canvas page.

Comment: Exactly Thanks and  sorry for mine english but that canvas Page itself  not opening for me and I have provided the different canvas url for it.

Comment: Then check the Canvas URL first, is that working? 

PS pls mark and accept the answer if that helped!

Comment: Hi I solved the problem. now facebook not provide a canvas URL until and unless you provide a namespace for an app. and after providing the namespace you get an canvas URL as https://apps.facebook.com/namespace_name @shadowfx thank you for your reply which help to get closer to a problem :)